# Are there any indeclinable adjectives?

Tags: adjective, declension, borrowing

I had until recently believed that only nouns could be "declinable" versus "indeclinable": most nouns follow set declensions patterns, while a few (mostly foreign, like *Abraham* from Hebrew, but some native, like *fas*) look the same in every form.

However, brianpck corrected me in his comment on [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6650/406), pointing out that the adjective *nēquam* is also indeclinable.

Are there any other indeclinable adjectives out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There certainly are other indeclinable adjectives:

- [*damnas*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddamnas)
- [*frugi*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=frux) (gramatically, this is really a "dative of service")
- [*nēquam*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=nequam)
- [*potis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dpotis) (though *pote* sometimes occurs in the neuter)
- [*quot*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquot) (also: *aliquot*)
- [*tŏt*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=tot) (also: *totidem*)
- And, after *tres*, almost every numerical adjective, e.g. *quattuor*, *decem*, *viginti*, *mille*, etc.

Allen & Greenough discusses this, along with many of the above examples, in [§122](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/irregularities-and-special-uses-adjectives), along with a mention of defective and common adjectives.